# Flutter TextField used twice in one stateless widget filled with previous value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So I have a stateless widget (AuthInput) that returns TextField.

I am using it twice in one stateless widget, when user clicks next second TextField appears, but the problem is that the second TextField is already filled with previous value. here is part of code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Auth>(builder: (context, auth, child) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 32),
            child: Builder(builder: (context) {
              switch (auth.step) {
                case AuthStep.Username:
                  return AuthInput(
                    hintText: 'username',
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      auth.username = val;
                    },
                  );
                case AuthStep.Password:
                  return AuthInput(
                    hintText: 'password',
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      auth.password = val;
                    },
                  );
              }
              return null;
            }),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
```

---

```
class AuthInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onChanged;
  final String hintText;
  final bool obscureText;
  AuthInput({
    Key key,
    this.onChanged,
    this.hintText,
    this.obscureText = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      obscureText: obscureText,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: hintText,
        focusColor: Colors.blue,
        hoverColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did `AuthInput` came from? Are you using a package or have you created a custom widget?

Comment: @ASADHAMEED I created custom widget, I'll add the code of the widget

Comment: Try removing the `key` parameter from AuthInput, if it works I'll explain it.

Comment: Also remove the `super(key: key)`

Comment: @ASADHAMEED nope result is same

Comment: Okay, undo the changes and try passing UniqueKey() as an argument to both the AuthInput fields.

Comment: If it still doesnot work, I'll try to reproduce the issue later and will let you know.

Comment: @ASADHAMEED thank you very much. it works now! If you'll post an answer would love to mark it as correct.

Comment: also, there is a funny thing happening now I've added unique key. I have an animation in parent widget it runs every 3 seconds and it makes inputed value disappear.

Comment: Okay, I'll like to try it now.

Comment: If you have a GitHub repo for this project please share the link, I would like to test it int he exact scenario.

Comment: @ASADHAMEED Sorry this is a private repo cannot share.

Comment: okay, I would be glad to help if I can become a contributor.